# Calculation order rules left shift "Lsh" in Javascript

Tags: javascript, math

I am trying to understand the mathematically correct order in calculations when using shifting.

I found Javascript seems to be doing calculations in priority order of:

^ * / + - << >>

A binary calculator for example the Calculator of Windows10 uses the priority order of:

<< >> ^ * / + -

But what is the mathematically correct order in this case?

for example:

Calculator
1 + 3 Lsh 3 - 1 (result: 24)

Javascript
1 + 3 << 3 - 1 (result: 16)

Try It:
http://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=F0L1LGPQX9T2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is no "mathematically correct order" for this

mathematics considers exponential, multiplication/division, and addition/subtraction, but bitwise operations come with programming languages, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations#Programming_languages

Answer (score 1):

Use [PEMDAS](https://www.purplemath.com/modules/orderops.htm) method: `Parentheses, Exponents, Multiplication and Division, and Addition and Subtraction`.

So it means correct order is `^ * / + - << >>`.

---

[JS Operator precedence table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence)

Comment: PEMDAS does not include bitwise shifts, so why do you think it applies here?

Comment: Thank you Justinas, the link helps alot to clarify things. So I guess its safe to say to always use grouping in case of shifting? since it solely depends on the language what order is used?